# My HTML form sends email but does not send from data. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-email, forms, http-post

As an intermediate web developer, I have a problem with my form not send inserted data(the email goes through but form data does not), I don't know if it is form or PHP script.

**HTML**

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
              <fieldset>
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
                </fieldset>
          </form>
```

**JS**

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible</p>').delay(5000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
 $from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
 $message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$to          = 'email@email.com';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);die;
?>
```

Please help as I am stuch here.

Comment: @Djave — Why? There are no file inputs in it.

Comment: Because you do not pass any data on the AJAX Call. Look at the jquery manual

Comment: I don't think that it really posts something. Because you override the post event and block all the other events `event.preventDefault();` You need to pass some POST data in your AJAX Call

Comment: pass all require data manually in ajax request

Comment: someone could easily spoof your contact form. You do not validate or check for post data nor do you even send any data via the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
> ```

Using `@` to suppress errors and warnings is generally considered to be a bad idea at the best of times. Doing it when you are trying to debug a problem is an exceptionally bad idea.

> ```
> form.submit(function(event){
>     event.preventDefault();
> ```

You use JavaScript to prevent your form from submitting.

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     url: $(this).attr('action'),
>     beforeSend: function(){
>         form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
>     }
> ```

Then you use JavaScript to make an HTTP request instead.

You set the URL to be the same as the form.

You don't send any data.

You don't set the method (so it defaults to GET).

If you want to send data from your JavaScript, then you have to actually send it.

The [jQuery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/) explains how to read form data. Don't forget to set the method too.